# Function postgres executed twice

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I created a function in Postgres, but it's executed twice,
this my function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.get_no_urut_pp (OUT urut1 character varying)
RETURNS character varying AS
$BODY$
BEGIN

    insert into no_urut_pp values (28);
    select max(nomor) into urut1 from no_urut_pp;
END;

$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
COST 100;
```

i call that function from java :

```
// java code;
public String getNoUrutPPService() {
    String hasil=null;
    con = dbEngine.getConnection();
    try {
        con.setAutoCommit(false);
        cs = con.prepareCall("{call get_no_urut_pp(?)}");
        cs.registerOutParameter(1, Types.VARCHAR);
        cs.execute();
        hasil = (String) cs.getObject(1);
        System.out.println(hasil);
        con.commit();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        LOG.error(e);
    } finally {
        closeConnetion();
    }
    return hasil;
}
```

I call from ajax from my jsp page

```
$.ajax({
        url : "getNoUrutPP",
        dataType : 'JSON', 
        type : 'post',
        success: function(res){
            $('#kodeFile').val('');
            if(res.hasil !== null){
                $('#kodeFile').val(res.hasil);
            }
        }
    });
```

is some think wrong in my function.

Comment: how you execute it?

Comment: i was edited ....

Comment: do you call `getNoUrutPPService` two times?

Comment: no, i call getNoUrutPPService by ajax one time

Comment: i would post my ajax call

Comment: To debug this, I typically add a `Thread.dumpStack();` to the Java method to see from _where_ it is called twice. It certainly isn't a problem with your Postgres function.

Comment: yes, i founded. thank  @a_horse_with_no_name, my mistake in calling ajax. I call ajax from select option onchange. it's loaded twice. firts load when select option load its content and secend load is when i select my select option. that why my function load twice. thank fo all